# Passing PHP MySQL Result Object to Function

Tags: php, mysql, function, object

I'm trying to take a MySQL result row and pass it to a function for processing but the row isn't getting passed. I'm assuming this is because the actual row comes back as a object and objects can't get passed to function?

E.G

```
function ProcessResult($TestID,$Row){
    global $ResultArray;
    $ResultArray["Sub" . $TestID] = $Row["Foo"] - $Row["Bar"];
    $ResultArray["Add" . $TestID] = $Row["Foo"] + $Row["Bar"];
}



$SQL = "SELECT TestID,Foo,Bar FROM TestResults WHERE TestDate !='0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
$Result= mysql_query($SQL$con);

    if(!$Result){
        // SQL Failed
        echo "Couldn't find how many tests to get";
    }else{

        $nRows = mysql_num_rows($Result);

        for ($i=0;$i<$nRows;$i++)
        {
            $Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);

            $TestID = $Row[TestID];

            ProcessResult($TestID,$Row);
        }

    }
```

What I need is $ResultArray populated with a load of data from the MySQL query. This isn't my actual application (I know there's no need to do this for what's shown) but the principle of passing the result to a function is the same.

Is this actually possible to do some how?

Dan

Comment: The MySQL extension is not recommended for writing new code. Instead, either the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: @DC_ is right. Anyway, what do you mean that the row is not passed?

Comment: `...and objects can't get passed to function?` Objects most certainly *can* be passed to a function. As an aside, they are passed by reference, but they are still passed.

Comment: Can you add the results of two `var_dump` (e.g. `var_dump($Row);`) one just before `ProcessResult` and the other just inside the function ProcessResult?

Comment: `mysql_query($SQL$con);` should be `mysql_query($SQL,$con);` The first is a syntax error. Not sure if this affects your program or if it was just a typo on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query($SQL$con);` should be `mysql_query($SQL,$con);` The first is a syntax error. Not sure if this affects your program or if it was just a typo on here.

I would recommend putting quotes around your array keys. `$row[TestID]` should be `$row["TestID"]`

The rest looks like it should work, although there are some strange ideas going on here.

Also you can do this to make your code a little cleaner.

```
if(!$Result){
    // SQL Failed
    echo "Couldn't find how many tests to get";
}else{

    while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
    {
        $TestID = $Row['TestID'];

        ProcessResult($TestID,$Row);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks All,There actually wasn't anything wrong with what I was doing - it was my SQL query which didn't fetch the right things in the first place! Not knowing if this was even possible caused me to question it first instead of looking at the obvious things.

Hopefully though if anyone else questions if it's possible to do this they will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array - [see more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

If you need an object, try `mysql_fetch_object()` function - [see more](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php)

Both array and object can be passed to a function. Thus, your code seems to be correct, except for one line. It should be:

```
$Result= mysql_query($SQL, $con);
```

or just:

```
$Result= mysql_query($SQL);
```